# For loop using arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a program that is to calculate taxes for payroll. I need a `for` loop to write the last name, first name, dept, rate, hours, earnings, fica, fedtax, statetax and netpay. I'm not thrown any errors when I run the program and can't seem to find why my output only displays the last name. There are two `.txt` files, one is blank for output and the other is listed below.

### This is the data content of my `.txt` file:

```
Adams               Paul               3      9.75     40.00
Allen               Cindy              2     11.45     48.00
Allen               Sarah              4     10.30     40.00
Baker               John               1     22.00     43.25
Baker               Toni               1     12.65     40.00
Baldwin             Cindy              2      7.90     25.50
Carson              Robert             1      8.35     52.50
Freeman             Sally              4     15.25     40.00
Garfield            James              3     22.00     40.00
Grimes              Kerri              3     16.50     35.00
Harris              Joan               2     18.65     51.00
Harris              John               2      9.00     47.50
Lawson              LeAnn              4     17.85     40.00
Mason               Debbie             4     22.00     41.50
Masters             Kenneth            3     16.10     40.25
Patterson           Roseanne           2     13.70     38.00
Peterson            Paul               2     22.00     44.00
Randall             Michael            3      8.00     41.00
Rogers              Sherry             1     16.50     30.00
Shepard             Steven             3     10.90     45.50
```

### This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using LibUtil;

classPayRoll
{

    const double FICA_RATE = 0.07;
    const double FED_TAX_RATE = 0.22;
    const double STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.05;
    const string INPUT_FILE_NAME = "PayrollDat.Txt";
    const string OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "PayrollReport.Txt";

    static uint numOfEmployees;
    static string[] lastNameArray = new string[51], firstNameArray = new string[51];
    static uint[] deptArray = new uint[51];
    static double[] rateArray = new double[51], hoursArray = new double[51];
    static double[] earningsArray = new double[51], ficaArray = new double[51];
    static double[] fedTaxArray = new double[51], stateTaxArray = new double[51];
    static double[] netPayArray = new double[51];
    static StreamReader fileIn;
    static StreamWriter fileOut;

    static void Main()
    {
        OpenFiles();
        InputData();
        CalcDetailPayroll();
        PrintReport();
        CloseFiles();
    }

    static void OpenFiles()
    {
        if (File.Exists(INPUT_FILE_NAME))
        {
            fileIn = File.OpenText(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was opened", INPUT_FILE_NAME);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} does not exist\n", INPUT_FILE_NAME);
            ConsoleApp.Exit();
        }
        fileOut = File.CreateText(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
        if (File.Exists(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME))
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was created\n", OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} could not be created\n", OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
            ConsoleApp.Exit();
        }
    }

    static void ParseLineIn(string lineIn, uint i)
    {
        string[] words = new string[5];

        lineIn = lineIn.Trim();
        while (Regex.IsMatch(lineIn, "[ ]{2}"))
            lineIn = lineIn.Replace("  ", " ");
        words = lineIn.Split(' ');
        lastNameArray[i] = words[0];

        i = 0;
        while (i <= numOfEmployees)
        {
            lastNameArray[i] = words[0];
            firstNameArray[i] = words[1];
            deptArray[i] = uint.Parse(words[2]);
            rateArray[i] = double.Parse(words[3]);
            hoursArray[i] = double.Parse(words[4]);
            i++;
        }
        //Add code to read in data into remaining arrays
    }

    static void InputData()
    {
        uint i;
        string lineIn;

        i = 0;
        while ((lineIn = fileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            i++;
            ParseLineIn(lineIn, i);
        }
        numOfEmployees = i;
    }

    static void CalcDetailPayroll()
    {
        uint i;
        double basePay, ovtPay;

        for (i = 1; i <= numOfEmployees; i++)
        {
            if (hoursArray[i] <= 40.0)
            {
                basePay = Math.Round(hoursArray[i] * rateArray[i]); //Calculate base pay 
                ovtPay = 0.00;
            }
            else
            {
                basePay = Math.Round(40 * rateArray[i]); //Calculate base pay
                ovtPay = Math.Round(rateArray[i] * (hoursArray[i] - 40.0) * 1.5); //Calculate overtime pay
            }
            //Calculate earnings, fica, fedTax, stateTax, and netPay 

            earningsArray[i] = basePay + ovtPay;
            ficaArray[i] = earningsArray[i] * FICA_RATE;
            fedTaxArray[i] = earningsArray[i] * fedTaxArray[i];
            stateTaxArray[i] = earningsArray[i] * STATE_TAX_RATE;
            netPayArray[i] = earningsArray[i] - (ficaArray[i] + fedTaxArray[i] + stateTaxArray[i]);
        }
    }

    static double Total(double[] doubleArray)
    {
        uint i;
        double total = 0.0;

        for (i = 1; i <= numOfEmployees; i++) ;
        total += earningsArray[i];
        return total;
    }

    static double Mean(double[] doubleArray)
    {
        uint i;
        double sum = 0.0;

        for (i = 1; i <= numOfEmployees; i++)
            sum += doubleArray[i];
        return sum / numOfEmployees;
    }

    static double Max(double[] doubleArray)
    {
        uint i;
        double max;

        max = doubleArray[1];
        for (i = 2; i <= numOfEmployees; i++)
            if (doubleArray[i] > max)
                max = doubleArray[i];
        return max;
    }

    static double Min(double[] doubleArray)
    {
        uint i;
        double min;
        double max;

        min = doubleArray[1];
        for (i = 2; i <= numOfEmployees; i++)
            if (doubleArray[i] < min)
                max = doubleArray[i];
        return min;
    }

    static void PrintReport()
    {
        uint i;

        fileOut.WriteLine("                                         Payroll Report                                                  ");
        fileOut.WriteLine();
        fileOut.WriteLine("   Last Name      First Name    Dept  Rate Hours  Earnings    FICA    Fed Tax  State Tax  Net Pay ");
        fileOut.WriteLine("--------------- --------------- ---- ----- ----- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------");
        for (i = 1; i <= numOfEmployees; i++)
        {
            fileOut.WriteLine("{0,-9} {1,9} {2,9} {3,9} {4,9} {5,9} {6,9} {7,9} {8,9} {9,9}",
               lastNameArray[i], firstNameArray[i], deptArray[i], rateArray[i],hoursArray[i],earningsArray[i],
               ficaArray[i],fedTaxArray[i],stateTaxArray[i],netPayArray[i]);
        }
        //Create for loop to display last name, firstname, dept, rate, hours, earnings, fica, fedTax, stateTax, and netPay

        fileOut.WriteLine("                                                 --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------");

            fileOut.WriteLine("{0,-49}{1,9:n} {2,9:n} {3,9:n} {4,9:n} {5,9:n}",
                          "Total", Total(earningsArray), Total(ficaArray),
                          Total(fedTaxArray), Total(stateTaxArray), Total(netPayArray));
            fileOut.WriteLine("{0,-49}{1,9:n} {2,9:n} {3,9:n} {4,9:n} {5,9:n}",
                              "Mean", Mean(earningsArray), Mean(ficaArray),
                              Mean(fedTaxArray), Mean(stateTaxArray), Mean(netPayArray));
            fileOut.WriteLine("{0,-49}{1,9:n} {2,9:n} {3,9:n} {4,9:n} {5,9:n}",
                              "Maximum", Max(earningsArray), Max(ficaArray),
                              Max(fedTaxArray), Max(stateTaxArray), Max(netPayArray));
            fileOut.WriteLine("{0,-49}{1,9:n} {2,9:n} {3,9:n} {4,9:n} {5,9:n}",
                              "Minimum", Min(earningsArray), Min(ficaArray),
                              Min(fedTaxArray), Min(stateTaxArray), Min(netPayArray));

    }

    static void CloseFiles()
    {
        fileIn.Close(); fileOut.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: There's way too much code here. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question into a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal)

Comment: Also, it's a pretty bad idea to have a number of arrays, you should create an Employee class and use a single array of that class

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger! The most important skill you will ever learn as a coder is to _debug your own code_. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: NEVER use double or float for money.  Use decimal.

Comment: Your Total, Mean, Max and Min methods all ignore array index zero. You skip index zero when calculating data for the arrays you pass to them (so maybe not an issue) yet you use index zero for your employee information arrays. Arrays start at zero, not one. Be consistent and don't use so many arrays here. Classes are your friend

Answer (score 0):

You should change the ParseLineIn method to use the index passed from the caller. Actually you are setting always the same index when you set the i to zero

```
static void ParseLineIn(string lineIn, uint i)
{
    string[] words = new string[5];

    lineIn = lineIn.Trim();
    while (Regex.IsMatch(lineIn, "[ ]{2}"))
        lineIn = lineIn.Replace("  ", " ");
    words = lineIn.Split(' ');
    lastNameArray[i] = words[0];

    // i = 0;
    // No loop needed, you are reading one line of data and setting 
    // the appropriate index in the arrays
    // while (i <= numOfEmployees)
    //{
        lastNameArray[i] = words[0];
        firstNameArray[i] = words[1];
        deptArray[i] = uint.Parse(words[2]);
        rateArray[i] = double.Parse(words[3]);
        hoursArray[i] = double.Parse(words[4]);
    //    i++;
    //}
}
```

Also notice that your Total method has an error in this line

```
for (i = 1; i <= numOfEmployees; i++) ;
```

remove the semicolon at the end of the for loop to allow the execution of the line the makes the sum.

Said all this, I really suggest you to discard this array approach and build a proper class that represent your data and collect the information in a List of such data. Actually your code allows only files with 50 lines and please remember that array in NET start at index zero.